# Why won't Apple Mail open after install of OS X El Capitan 10.11? Any ideas?

Tags: mail.app, macos, beta-seed-program

I have installed the latest beta of OS X, El Capitan 10.11. The mail app said it needed to index mail. when it finished that process the mail app crashed. Now it refuses to open. Mail has been rendered unusable with this upgrade, for me.

Anyone have any ideas of things I could try to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: I can share the error report, if needed.

Comment: 10.11 Beta (15A262e) Thanks for the response. I have rebooted twice.

Comment: the error report has too many characters to post

Comment: reset the RAM as well. Still nada.

Comment: Good info. Please add these to your question using the edit link.

Comment: Does your Mac have the only copy of the emails? Or are there copies of all mail on the server too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to remove a PGP plug-in from /Library/Mail/Bundles to get the Mail App running again.

Just open Mail and immediately open Accounts, disable the accounts one by one to find out which one is causing the crash. Then delete this account completely and restart Mail. Then add the account all over again. It worked on my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue - in my case it was caused by an account with incorrect settings.  Yosemite tolerated this while El Capital crashes.  I followed the suggestion and disabled wi-fi.  Mail loaded.  When I enabled wi-fi, it crashed immediately.  I disabled the account and now it seems to work. El Capitan seems overly finicky on this.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well in El Capitan Beta 4. A simple reboot solved the problem. Since you also tried that, i'd suggest

- empty caches (using cleanmymac or similars)
- reset PRAM at startup

Comment: i will give those a shot.

Comment: too bad you can't Repair Permissions anymore, that would have been another great suggestion (what a stupid *update* in El Capitan)

Comment: @GothicAsFuck Doesn't El Cap add some new process that automatically manages permissions such that a repair is never needed?

Comment: @user24601 True indeed, but if I remember correctly those processes are actually engaged only when you install new updates or new software.

Comment: thanks for the answers. the emails are on icloud as well. i ended up clearing caches, resetting PRAM....and then just doing a complete Time Machine back-up of my system from two days ago. I have not updated to the latest beta.

Comment: I thought repair permissions was kinda like snake oil? I certainly haven't seen much compelling evidence that it ever did much—mostly because people do it along with several other actions that may have also helped.

Comment: @Sizzle so you are sorted now?

Comment: yes. i time machine'd back and all "normal"

Comment: but actually some emails are showing in notifications but are not showing up in inbox yet.

Comment: Good grief! In my case, it would open a gazillion windows and then hang and crash. Only Force Quit worked. Had to remove the accounts and do a PRAM reset. Pretty annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and needed to clean out anything that had index in the name from this path: 
~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/

Now it seems to be coming back to life again.

Answer (score 0):

Mail seems to stumble over incompatible bundles, at least on my system. I had to manually move Mail plugins installed in `/Library/Mail/Bundles` and `~/Library/Mail/Bundles` out of the way to get Mail back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Mail would crash immediately upon attempting to open.  My issue was resolved when I turned off wifi, which kept the mail accounts offline. I could open mail with wifi off but when I turned it back on, it would crash.  I then could see mail, which allowed me to disable accounts.  With wifi off, I deleted some of the accounts until I found which was the problem, which seemed to be the ones that I didn't use anyhow. I turned wifi back on and it seems to do fine now.  It took a few times of turning it off and back on to isolate the issue.

Comment: Anything special these accounts have in common?

Answer (score 0):

I quit mail, removed everything in ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/ and relaunch mail.. then it started to import mail again and created V3 folder

Answer (score 0):

If you have a symbolic link to move the mail to another drive, remove the link.  That worked for me.  Maybe there is new type of links in el capitan.  will try it again when it fills

Answer (score 0):

This was a quick fix I found:

Settings > Internet accounts > uncheck mail for each account > open mail > preferences > re-enable each account

Answer (score 0):

Combining suggestions from Tim Lynch & Bella worked for me.
Now Mail half way through downloading 20,000 emails !

By the way, under Yosemite, Mail had been crawling; so far so great with El Capitan; perhaps things will change when all 20K messages are downloaded!]

[iMac 27-inch late 2009; 12 GB]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to answer the question. This looks more like a comment. Please move this to the comments section of the question.